# Computing the integral $\int_{-1}^{2} \left( |x| + |1-x| \right) {\rm d} x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value

I'm having trouble with one of the exercises, I have to split the integral for the absolute value but I can't manage to algebraic find the boundaries for the integral.

$$\int_{-1}^{2} \left( |x| + |1-x| \right) {\rm d} x$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value

Comment: As the comment above says, if you look at the abs value, you may have to split the integral into 3 integrals.... one from -1 to 0, the next from 0 to 1 and the last one from 1 to 2.  What are the values of the functions in each of these 3 intervals ? Hope this helps

Comment: Thats not really the problem, the problem is how to retrieve these values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|x|=x$ when $x>0$ and $|x|=-x$ when $x<0$.  Similarly, $|1-x|=1-x$ when $1-x>0$ and $|1-x|=x-1$ when $1-x<0$.  We end up with three different cases: $x<0$, $0<x<1$, and $x>1$.  For example, when $x<0$, we have

$$|x|+|1-x|=-x+1-x=1-2x$$

which you should have no problem integrating now that the absolute values are gone.  You should be able to handle the other two cases.

Answer (score 7):

There are three regions:

$$\int_{-1}^{2} (|x|+|1-x|) dx=\int_{-1}^{0}-2x+1 \ dx +\int_{0}^{1}1\ dx+\int_{1}^{2}2x-1 \ dx=5.$$

To verify this, take a look at the following figure:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 6):

$$\int_{-1}^2 dx (|x|+|1-x|) = \int_{-1}^0 dx (-x + 1-x) + \int_0^1 dx (x+1-x) + \int_1^2 dx [x-(1-x)] $$

Go...

Answer (score 1):

The point where $|x|$ 'changes form' (between $x$ and $-x$) is when $x=0$.

The point where $|1-x|$ changes form is when $1-x = 0$

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the actual integration, just remember that you're summing the area under the curves.  Notice that $$\int_{-1}^{2} (|x|+|1-x|) dx$$ equals $$\int_{-1}^{2} (|x|) dx + \int_{-1}^{2} (|1-x|) dx$$  Then just draw both parts on a graph.  You'll see that each part specifies two triangles: one with an area of 0.5 and the other with an area of 2.  Add that up $(2 + 0.5 + 2 + 0.5)$ to get 5